# how python "==" compare two identifiers

Tags: python

I am curious about how python determine what 'rule' to use for compare to types, is the memory address?  eg:

```
In [2]: int==int
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: whatever the object's type does for `__eq__`

Answer (score 6):

Types don't implement a value equality test, so Python falls back to the standard implementation, testing for *identity*.

In other words, `int == int` falls back to `int is int`